# VBA Macro isn't finding a match even though values are an exact match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a Macro to loop through a sheet looking for matches bases on multiple criteria. I'm at the point where I want to loop through one more time where (i,13) = "Account details match but payment differs" but use column (i,12) as a match against (J, 14).

When I add this loop though:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(PensionArr)
    match = False
    For J = 1 To UBound(PayrollArr)
        If CStr(PensionArr(i, 13)) = "Account details match but payment differs" Then

            If CStr(PensionArr(i, 12)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 14)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                PensionArr(i, 13) = "Complete match"
                Exit For


                'Looks for SC&AC Match but Amount doesn't
            ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details match but payment differs"


                'Looks Amount Match but SC&AC don't
            ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details do not match but payment is correct"

            End If
        End If
    Next J
Next i
```

It populated (i, 13) as "Person not found" which should only be the outcome if the person doesn't exist in the second sheet.

Without the above loop though it populates (i,13) with 1 of 2 values depending on what doesn't match between sheets. There's no "Person not found" until I add the above loop in.

My entire code is:

```
Sub PensionCheckAccName()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation =     xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim Pension As Worksheet
    Dim Payroll As Worksheet

    Dim cell As Range

    Dim i As Long, J As Long

    Dim PensionArr As Variant
    Dim PayrollArr As Variant

    Dim match As Boolean

    Dim PensionRng As Range
    Dim PayrollRng As Range

    Set Pension = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pensions Bank")
    Set Payroll =  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PensionItrent")

    Set PensionRng = Pension.Range("A2",  Pension.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 13))
    Set PayrollRng = Payroll.Range("A2", Payroll.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 14))

    PensionArr = PensionRng.Value2
    PayrollArr = PayrollRng.Value2

    For i = 1 To UBound(PensionArr)
        match = False
        For J = 1 To UBound(PayrollArr)
            If CStr(PensionArr(i, 6)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 7)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 13)) <> "Complete match" Then


                'Looks for a complete match across SC,AC,Amount

                If CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Complete match"
                    Exit For


                    'Looks for SC&AC Match but Amount doesn't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details match but payment differs"


                    'Looks Amount Match but SC&AC don't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details do not match but payment is correct"

                End If
            End If
        Next J
    Next i


    For i = 1 To UBound(PensionArr)
        match = False
        For J = 1 To UBound(PayrollArr)
            If CStr(PensionArr(i, 13)) = "Account details match but payment differs" Then

                If CStr(PensionArr(i, 12)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 14)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Complete match"
                    Exit For


                    'Looks for SC&AC Match but Amount doesn't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details match but payment differs"


                    'Looks Amount Match but SC&AC don't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details do not match but payment is correct"

                End If
            End If
        Next J
    Next i


    For i = 1 To UBound(PensionArr)
        match = False
        For J = 1 To UBound(PayrollArr)
            If CStr(PensionArr(i, 13)) = "Person not found" Then

                If CStr(PensionArr(i, 12)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 14)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Complete match"
                    Exit For


                    'Looks for SC&AC Match but Amount doesn't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details match but payment differs"


                    'Looks Amount Match but SC&AC don't
                ElseIf CStr(PensionArr(i, 4)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 5)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 5)) <> CStr(PayrollArr(J, 6)) And CStr(PensionArr(i, 8)) = CStr(PayrollArr(J, 9)) Then
                    PensionArr(i, 13) = "Account details do not match but payment is correct"
                End If
            End If
        Next J
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(PensionArr)
        If PensionArr(i, 13) = "" Then
            PensionArr(i, 13) = "Person not found"
        End If
    Next i

    PensionRng.Value = PensionArr

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

Any help would be good as I'm trying to use the above code to compare each sheet based on multiple values but there's a lot of rows where 3 of the 4 columns are identical and they are only made unique by the 4th column. When I try to use the 4th column to make the rows unique for comparison (the first loop) it then doesn't match 136 rows.

I haven't been using VBA for very long so any tips are welcome.

Let me know if you need more information

Many thanks,

Matt

Comment: In addition, the below excel formula finds a match using the same criteria i'm trying to use in my VBA Macro not sure if this is helpful with my above issue.        {=INDEX(PensionItrent!K:K,MATCH(1,(D174=PensionItrent!E:E)*('Pensions Bank'!E174=PensionItrent!F:F)*('Pensions Bank'!L174=PensionItrent!N:N)*('Pensions Bank'!H174=PensionItrent!I:I),0))}

Comment: Are there any text case differences in the text you are comparing? like "Joe" vs "joe" that might account for text not matching? If so you could add `Option Compare Text` to ignore text case.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Hi, I can't provide the exact data as it's not masked but 6 of the columns are numbers and I formatted the columns as numbers with no decimal places. 2 columns are amount and I formatted as a custom format (the one right at the bottom) and 2 columns are general which are the only columns that have text in them, but the format of the columns aren't text. What strikes me as odd is that if I do a formula to do what my Macro should do it works fine as intended and it finds the matches but if I use the additional loop in my Sub it then doesn't work at all.

Comment: I can provide the column names though. From sheet one: Transaction type,Originating Sort Code,Originating Account number,Destination sort code,Destination account number,Destination account name,Destination account code,Amount,Processing date.RTI Ref.User last name,Reference,Match Status,Investigation Status,Completed By,Completed Date 
From Sheet 2 -Originating Sort Code,Originating Account No,Originating Account Name,Payment type,Destination Account Sort Code,Destination Account Number,Destination Account Name,Payee Name,Payment Value,Reference Surname,Forename1,Field 7,Payroll Number

Comment: This is an embarrassing question!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order of my loops. I was setting the "Person not found" right at the end yet trying to loop through rows with that set in (i, 13) prior to it being set.

I then moved the problem loop at the top of my question to the end after everything had been set and it worked straight away.

I just needed to reorder my loops to get it to do what I wanted.

Thanks anyway for trying